# Password from old workbook copied over in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I copied a worksheet from a password-protected workbook into a new workbook. Now every time I open this new workbook, it prompts me for the password from the old workbook. However, clicking either OK or Cancel lets me into the new workbook with no issues.

Is there a way to remove this old workbook's password? It's completely independent of the new workbook's password.

Answer (score 0):

In that worksheet, either:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd>
- Right click the worksheet name, click <kbd>Protect Sheet</kbd>

Then untick "Protect worksheet and contents of locked cells" and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Save the file and relaunch it.

Comment: Tricky part is, I deleted that worksheet in hopes of that fixing it.

Comment: so that copied worksheet is deleted but still get that password prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Open the new workbook (assuming Excel 2007 here) and select the entire worksheet (CTRL-A) from cell A1 or click the top left hand corner of the worksheet.

Remove the Password on the sheet by right-clicking the TAB down the bottom of the sheet and select UnProtect Sheet. Enter the password.

Next, right click the selected range and select Format Cells. Click Protection tab and **untick** the Locked option. This will remove any "protection" on cells. You want to remove all restrictions.

Now SAVE the workbook and next time you open it, all protection and passwords have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to break the connection to the old Workbook using **Edit Links** in the **Data** ribbon